# Set focus on selected item of listview

Tags: listview, focus

I have a gridview within my listview (xaml)
I set the selected item in my listview by a index value. This works fine.

Now I want the keyboard focus to be on the selected item.

I'm able to set focus to the listview itself, but not to the selected item in the listview.

```
// Set selected item at index : i
   listview1.SelectedIndex = i;

// Sets focus to listview
   listview1.Focus();

// Try to set focus to selected item
   ListViewItem myitem = listview1.Items[i] as ListViewItem;   


   myitem.Focus();
```

dgrid1.xaml

```
        <ListView Name="listview1" >

            <ListView.View>

                <GridView ColumnHeaderToolTip="Multiple Category Information">                        

                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Enquiry_Number}" Header="Enquiry number"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Consignee_Ref}" Header="Consignee reference"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Booking_Reference}" Header="Booking reference"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Contract_Number}" Header="Contract Number"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Invoice_Number}" Header="Invoice Number"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Date_Invoice}" Header="Invoice Date"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Status}" Header="Status"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Period_Enquiry}" Header="Period Enquiry"/>
                    <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Consignee}" Header="Consignee"/>
                </GridView>

            </ListView.View>

        </ListView>
```

dgrid1.xaml.cs

```
// Call the DataManager Class which will collect the data and fill the data set with it
DataManager.BindFilteredData(dts);     

public static void BindFilteredData(DataSet dts)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString))
        {
            sql = "SELECT Enquiry_Number, Consignee_Ref, Booking_Reference, Contract_Number, Invoice_No, Date_Invoice, [Status], Period_Enquiry, Consignee FROM ConsHead";

            using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, connection))
            {                    
                adapter.Fill(dts);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: can't you use listview1.Selecteditem.focus ?

Comment: listview1.SelectedItem.focus();
This gives "object does not contain a definition for 'focus' and no extension method...etc

Comment: can you show some xaml (nested gridview in listview). Enables me to copy your problem.

Comment: I found a work around. I realised that after everything is loaded and the specific item is selected, the listview does not have focus at this moment. If I press the TAB key the focus jumps to the selected item in the listview. So I Simulated a TAB key press event programatically - so my item gets focus after loading the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a work around. I realised that after everything is loaded and the specific item is selected, the listview does not have focus at this moment. If I press the TAB key the focus jumps to the selected item in the listview. So I Simulated a TAB key press event programatically - so my item gets focus after loading the window

Answer (score 0):

It work if listview.TabOrder is set to 0.